# Network mode container in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

With plain docker I can use network mode container like this:

```
docker run -d --name container-b --network container:container-a <image>
```

Can this be achieved using docker-compose?

```
services:
  service-b:
    container_name: container-b
    network_mode: "container:container-a"
```

Leads to:

```
ERROR: Please provide 'network_mode: "bridge"' or 'network_mode: "host"' in your docker-compose.yaml
```

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: Yes and no. We weren't using the real docker-compose. There is a wrapper around the original binary that doesn't support the desired network_mode.

Answer (score 1):

I have a docker-compose file with version '2.1', but I am able to do this:

```
services:
  service-b:
    container_name: container-b
    network_mode: service:container-a
```

This makes all of my `container-b` traffic flow through `container-a`

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#network_mode

> Note
>
> This option is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode.
>
> network_mode: "host" cannot be mixed with links.

It won't work if your `docker-compose` "wrapper" uses `docker stack deploy` under the hood.

You would have to use something like this:

`docker network create some-other-network -d bridge --attachable --scope swarm`

... where `some-other-network` is bound to the target container.

And then:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  my-service:
    image: ...
    networks:
      - some-other-network
    
...

networks:
  some-other-network:
    external: true
```